# Choregraphe: How can I stop NAO from listening/ turn his eyes blue?

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

Using Choregraphe, I am building an app for NAO. I need to turn his LED eyes to different colours but whenever he is "listening" to me his eyes and ears automatically turn blue. How can I stop that from happening?

P.S. I am using a Dialog box to manage all his actions.
P.S.2.0 Autonomous life HAS to be kept on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General idea**

You need every topic that includes speech recognition rules to be unloaded, using [`ALDialog.unloadTopic`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/interaction/dialog/aldialog-api.html?highlight=aldialog#ALDialogProxy::unloadTopic__ssCR). Otherwise you can distinguish managing the actions from the dialogue, so that to enable the dialogue only when needed.

**With Choregraphe**

If you are using a dialog box, you can use [an output of nature `onStopped`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/software/choregraphe/objects/box_input_output.html#output-of-a-box), and trigger it from QiChat, like in [this example](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/software/choregraphe/tutos/dialog_topic.html#connecting-qichat-script-and-animations):

```
u:(...) ... $myOutput=1
```

When the output is triggered, the box is stopped, the topics are unloaded, the chat stops, and therefore the robot stops listening. To restart the chat, you can add an extra input of nature `onStart`, and react to it in the dialog box:

```
u:(e:myInput) ...
```

See [this tutorial](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/getting_started/samples/sample_story.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying @Victor.  I read the link you provided and tried to make it work by adding a Python Script box. There is only one topic and its called Traffic_Lights_GR so I ended up using this inside the Python Script box:
.
.
**`    def onInput_onStart(self):
        #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
        ALDialog.unloadTopic("Traffic_Lights_GR")
        pass
`**
It didn't work. Could you please help?

Comment: If you could elaborate on the otherwise part too i'd be so grateful, cause it would be ideal for the dialog to start working again when I wish.

Comment: Please detail "it didn't" work with details about your project and about the exact error / problem you encounter.

Comment: The project is just NAO saying whatever by using the Dialog Box. Through the Dialog box i enable the "game". The game is just him standing there and turning his eyes green orange and red, each with a specific timer of course, like a traffic light. Because of the "listening" mode NAO enters, the eye-LEDs don't change to green orange or red but instead they stay on that circling blue mode that he does when he listens. So i need to turn this listening mode off. I tried what you said and added a Python Script box where i added the code (look above) but it didnt work. Thats the whole explanation.

Comment: I don't know if i added the code described in the link in the wrong place, but he is still in listening mode when the Python Script Box is run. I am using Choregraphe by the way I do not know if this is known.

Comment: You could use [ALDialog.getActivatedTopics](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-interaction-engines/aldialog/aldialog-api#ALDialogProxy::getActivatedTopics) to double check that all topis are properly deactivated or unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

To whoever still needs an answer to this you can just stop the dialog box from 'working'. This will make the eyes stop going blue but also stop NAO from understanding words, but if you can find a solution around that, like add another dialog/say box after you utilise the non-blue-eyes-mode, then you are good to go. You can stop dialog by typing *$onStopped=1* in the .top file or by connecting a line to the dialog's *onStop* input.